wsl.localhost\Ubuntu keeps randomly becoming inaccessible
I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via WSL2 on Windows 11. Consistently, however, Ubuntu suddenly stops working and a dialogue box pops up saying "wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04 is not accessible". This can happen even when it is left in the background or even when there is no Ubuntu terminal running at all. The Ubuntu terminal will not show any text when opened thereafter. Neither can I access the files in Ubuntu through the file explorer when this happens. Additionally, typing wsl and wslconfig.exe /l, among other things, into powershell causes it to freeze
To resolve this, I have to run cmd.exe as administrator and type:
taskkill -IM vmwp.exe -IM wsl.exe -IM wslhost.exe -IM wslservice.exe /F
However, the respite is only temporary, and Ubuntu tends to crash again sometime later. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu LTS, WSL (have tried both 2.2.4 and 2.3.17), and turning windows features off and back on again. However, nothing has helped. I would appreciate any suggestions/advice on the issue. Thank you
